# How to create a subclass of the datetime.time class

Tags: python, datetime

I am trying to create a subclass of the datetime.time class. The problem lies in the `__new__` constructor I think. I've tried pretty much everything I could possibly think of:

```
class new_time(datetime.time):
    def __init__(self, *args):
        super().__new__(self, args)
new_time = new_time(1)
```

Which returns: `TypeError: datetime.time.__new__(X): X is not a type object (new_time)`

```
class new_time(datetime.time):
    def __new__(self, *args):
        super().__new__(self, args)
new_time = new_time(1)
```

Which returns: `TypeError: an integer is required (got type tuple)`

Any help would be a huge help, thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not completely sure in this is what you're looking for, but if you're just trying to pass the integer to your function, do this

```py
class new_time(datetime.time):
    def __new__(self, *args):    
        super().__new__(self, args[0])
new_time = new_time(1)
```

That just selects the first entry in the tuple and uses that for the argument.

Comment: I realized I was just being stupid and forgetting that *args is just a tuple of positional args - so you can just unpack them with *args if you want all of the arguments instead of args[0]. Sorry for correcting an answer to my own question, you really did help a ton.